# Custom builded table (header grouping), editing. Handsontable

Tags: handsontable

I've created a table with header groups and I completed the table with data this [data](http://tinyurl.com/pq3nv6n). Problem is with the editing. When I'm clicking on some price cell in table, I get error in Chrome console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined

Can someone help me to solve this problem? How can I edit the prices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to follow what you're doing with your data, what with all those nested loops and hard coded values. But here is what's going on, more or less.

The 'contains' error has to do with the way you're supplying the data sources. The editor will try and edit the data source when you open it. However, if it is `undefined`, then it will inevitably throw an error, in this case it does some sort of check with `contains` and throws when it goes `undefined.contains()`.

What you need to do is ensure every cell has a source correctly linked to it, otherwise you'll keep getting this error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved this problem. But now I got new and I hope you can help me again. Now my table display correct data, but when I'm editing some value or when I scroll horizontal other data going crazy. Also I got problem with header. It should display from 1 to 14.  http://tinyurl.com/nofkpty

Comment: Please just mark this question as answered and open a new one with more detail.